# Activemq not start in linux mint17

Tags: activemq-classic, linux-mint

Please see the following console output after executing activemq console 
command:

/opt/apache-activemq-5.5.1/bin $ sudo activemq console
sudo: /var/lib/sudo/vivek writable by non-owner (040777), should be mode 0700
[sudo] password for vivek: 
INFO: Loading '/usr/share/activemq/activemq-options'
INFO: Using java '/usr/bin/java'
INFO: Starting in foreground, this is just for debugging purposes (stop process by pressing CTRL+C)
INFO: changing to user 'activemq' to invoke java
mkdir: missing operand
Try 'mkdir --help' for more information.
Java Runtime: Oracle Corporation 1.8.0_45 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
  Heap sizes: current=502784k  free=492256k  max=502784k
    JVM args: -Xms512M -Xmx512M -Dorg.apache.activemq.UseDedicatedTaskRunner=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/lib/activemq/tmp -Dactivemq.classpath=/var/lib/activemq/conf; -Dactivemq.home=/usr/share/activemq -Dactivemq.base=/var/lib/activemq/ -Dactivemq.conf=/var/lib/activemq/conf -Dactivemq.data=/var/lib/activemq/data
ACTIVEMQ_HOME: /usr/share/activemq
ACTIVEMQ_BASE: /var/lib/activemq
ACTIVEMQ_CONF: /var/lib/activemq/conf
ACTIVEMQ_DATA: /var/lib/activemq/data
Loading message broker from: xbean:activemq.xml
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute start task. Reason: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [activemq.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [activemq.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute start task. Reason: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [activemq.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [activemq.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:98)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:148)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:257)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:111)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [activemq.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [activemq.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:111)
    at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:104)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
    at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:64)
    at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:52)
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1.(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:108)
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createApplicationContext(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:108)
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createBroker(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:72)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:71)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:54)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.startBroker(StartCommand.java:115)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:74)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [activemq.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
    ... 25 more
ERROR: java.lang.Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [activemq.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [activemq.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
java.lang.Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [activemq.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [activemq.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:99)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:148)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:257)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:111)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [activemq.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [activemq.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:111)
    at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:104)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
    at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:64)
    at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:52)
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1.(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:108)
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createApplicationContext(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:108)
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createBroker(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:72)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:71)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:54)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.startBroker(StartCommand.java:115)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:74)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [activemq.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
    ... 25 more

Comment: looks like it can't find 'activemq.xml' fix that and things should start working.

Comment: Yes ,It not find activemq.xml . I just download the  activemq.tar.gz. file from site and extract in /opt.  next place command as above post directed as  product's  site.   I searched all extracted folder , i didn't find activemq.xml.Please help me to get  instal active mq properly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to deploy the configuration file in the activemq/conf path.
You can download the last configuration file:
http://activemq.apache.org/xml-configuration.html
. I had the same issue deploying activemq on Ubuntu using apt-get.
A configuration file was stored in a different path:

```
/etc/activemq/instances-available/main/activemq.xml
```

I linked this file into a /var/lib/activemq/conf folder

```
sudo su -
su activemq
mkdir /var/lib/activemq/conf
ln -s /etc/activemq/instances-available/main/activemq.xml /var/lib/activemq/conf/
```